# regex to match specific words hyphenated at arbitrary positions and split across two lines

Tags: regex, multiline, hyphenation

I wish to search a text file for a given word that may optionally be hyphenated at an unknown position within the word and split across consecutive lines.

eg. match "hyphenated" within:

```
This sentence contains a hyphena-
ted word.
```

Closest (unattractive) solution:

```
"h\(-\s*\n\s*\)\?y\(-\s*\n\s*\)\?p\(-\s*\n\s*\)\?h\(-\s*\n\s*\)\?e\(-\s*\n\s*\)\?n\(-\s*\n\s*\)\?a\(-\s*\n\s*\)\?t\(-\s*\n\s*\)\?e\(-\s*\n\s*\)\?d"
```

I'm hoping that some regex-foo stronger than mine can come up with a regex that clearly includes the word being searched for, ie. I'd like to see "hyphenated" in there. I haven't found a way to encode something like the following (which would be buggy anyway, since it would match "hy-ted"):

```
"{prefix-of:hyphenated}{hyphen/linebreak}{suffix-of:hyphenated}"
```

I realize that pre-processing the document to collapse such words would make the search simpler but I'm looking for a regex that I can use in a context where this won't be possible due to the tools involved.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that `hy-phen-ated` should also match, I think this is a case where regex *alone* isn't the right way to go.

I would do this (not knowing your language, I've used pseudo code):

1. remove hyphens and newlines from input
2. match cleaned input with `.*hyphenated.*`

All languages can achieve step 1. trivially, and the code would be so much more readable.

Comment: This still kind of clashes with the OP's requirement that no preprocessing of the input is possible, though I can't imagine right now in what context you are able to match with regex, but not able to preprocess the input text.

Comment: I didn't want to clutter the question with the extra detail, but it's a legacy app that tries to be smart about formatting and provides a regex search, but breaks searchability due to hyphenation.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work.  If you have many words to search for, you would probably want to create a script to generate the search pattern for you.

```
[h\-]+\s*[y\-\s]+[p\-\s]+[h\-\s]+[e\-\s]+[n\-\s]+[a\-\s]+[t\-\s]+[e\-\s]+d\b
```

I don't think you mentioned which language you are using, but I tested this with .Net.

Here's a simple python script that will generate search patterns:

```
# patterngen.py
# Usage:  python patterngen.py <word>
# Example:  python patterngen.py hyphenated

word = sys.argv[1]
pattern = '[' + word[0] + r'\-]+\s*'

for i in range(1,len(word)-1):
    pattern = pattern + r'[' + word[i]
    pattern = pattern + r'\-\s]+'

pattern = pattern + word[-1] + r'\b'
print pattern
```

Comment: That's scarcely better than OP's effort. I think we're looking for something a little more sophisticated.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this, just right of the bat, is to "slide" the hyphenation like this:

```
hyphenated|h(-\s*\n\s*)yphenated|hy(-\s*\n\s*)phenated|hyp(-\s*\n\s*)henated|hyph(-\s*\n\s*)enated|hyphe(-\s*\n\s*)nated|hyphen(-\s*\n\s*)ated|hyphena(-\s*\n\s*)ted|hyphenat(-\s*\n\s*)ed|hyphenate(-\s*\n\s*)d
```

Reads better, but I don't really know how this stands performance wise to your original pattern.

---

Yet another idea is to first narrow the search with a pattern along these lines:

```
h[hypenatd]{0,9}(-\s*\n*\s)?[hypenatd]{0,9}
```

and then match within the results of this one.

In fact, if I'm not mistaken, if you match with groups like this:

```
(h[hypenatd]{0,9})(?:-\s*\n*\s)?([hypenatd]{0,9})
```

then the occurences of the word `hyphenated` are all the matches where, pseudocodily:

```
(match.group1 + match.group2) == "hyphenated"
```